# How to apply use IN keyword in NHibernate Criteria API?

Tags: hibernate

Hi I am working on `Criteria` API ,I want to fetch the users from db by using `Criteria` API.
It's working fine but I want to write query like this

```
Select * from EMP where empName LIKE '%bhan' or empName LIKE '%HAR' AND dominid=3;
```

How can I write this query by using  `Criteria` API in `NHiberbate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has some discrepancies `IN` is not the same and does not produce the same results as `LIKE`

You can add an `NHibernate.Criterion.ICriterion` object to an `NHibernate.ICriteria` object the following way.

```
//create the criteria
ICriteria _criteria = CurrentSession.CreateCriteria<Employee>();

//create a disjunction
var disjunction = NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Disjunction();

//form the disjunction
disjunction.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Like("empName", "bhan", NHibernate.Criterion.MatchMode.Anywhere));
disjunction.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Like("empName", "HAR", NHibernate.Criterion.MatchMode.Anywhere));

//add the disjunction to the criteria object
_criteria.Add(disjunction);

_criteria.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Eq("dominid", 3));
```

Or you can add an `IN` clause to the criteria.

```
_criteria.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.In("Entity_Property", An_Array_Of_Values));
```